# Error in transferring Multisim design to Ultiboard

Tags: multisim, ultiboard

I have this problem in Multisim 14, I'm trying to transfer my design in the Ultiboard but when I do, these red circles on the edge of the PCB layout keep appearing.
What could be causing this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am no expert on the software packages you are using, however there is usually an error list somewhere. Perhaps you can find the error message. If it is still unclear post the message to your question to get a better response. My guess is that it is some sort of placement error, out of keepin or off board or something.

Answer (score 1):

The errors shown in your update can indicate a few things to check:

1. Check your board outline (IE make sure it exists.)
2. Check if you have a design rule for net to board outline spacing and the dimension, make sure there are no nets within that distance.